# Get subtotal per "section" on dynamic ranges

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, circular-dependency

Quick question. I've been looking for a solution to get subtotals on ranges from a Google Sheet. Since the sheets are based on different services there's no fixed data in them. Rows can be added and deleted all the time. Shown below is a piece of the sheet.

```
Original Data

Section                               Hours

Preparations    
- Project start                       1
- Repos                               2
- Dockers                             3
- Domainnames                         4
    
Page 1  
- User Interface & User Experience    1
- Login                               2
- Dashboard                           3
- Account management                  4
    
Page 2  
- User Interface & User Experience    1
- Login                               2
- Dashboard                           3
    
Page 3  
- Testing                             1
- Release & deployment                2
```

```
Desired solution: 

Section                               Section total

Preparations                          10
- Project start                       
- Repos                               
- Dockers                             
- Domainnames                         
    
Page 1                                10  
- User Interface & User Experience    
- Login                               
- Dashboard                           
- Account management                  
    
Page 2                                6
- User Interface & User Experience    
- Login                               
- Dashboard                           
    
Page 3                                3
- Testing                              
- Release & deployment
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDHOn.png)

Shown on the left is what I fill in manually, which contains sections and subitems belonging to a section. The subitems have hours assigned to them.

The part on the right is what I would like to achieve, the sections showing a total number of hours of all subitems under a specific section. However, as mentioned lines and sections can be added and deleted and I like it to be as dynamic as possible, so I don't have to make any changes by hand in the section on the right side, if lines are added or hours are changed.

I've tried several things and got some help along the way, however I still haven't got the solution where the section on the right is generated all automatically.

Here's a link to the sheet shown above: [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fNRn8FGHEvnjX7wX9FAcyVl8-OJIg8q-DOLJva1Gpdg/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Allard

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of your sheet and the dynamic nature of your data, it would be cumbersome to make a single formula to get the subtotal for all the columns, but you can do these:

1. To populate column D you can use `=ARRAYFORMULA(A3:A)`.
2. Include two empty rows, top and bottom, in the sum formulas that are in column E. For example, in E5 you can use `=SUM(B5:B10)`, in E11 you can use `=SUM(B11:B16)`, and so on. This way, if you insert another row to add a subsection it will be included in the formula automatically.

The caveat of course is you need to add another `=SUM` formula manually if you add another whole section.

**Sample:**

[image]